# What is a better word for "treatment" in the given statement?

Tags: meaning

When I try to convert from English to Russian the following statement:

> If you are going to contact someone you should use either his or her exact name or the common form of treatment.

then Bing translator considers the word "treatment" as a medical treatment.

Is this statement correct and clear or ambiguous?

If the statement is confusing but its sense is clear for you then how is is better to rewrite it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Form of address* seems to be what you are getting at.

> If you are going to contact someone you should use either his or her exact name or the common form of address.

For instance, the common form of address in English, when the name of the addressee is unknown, is Sir for a man, Madam for a woman, or if it is not known whether the addressee is male or female, it is common to use the salutation *Dear Sir or Madam*.

Comment: It is funny because when i looked in a vocabulary English equivalent of addressing to somebody I got "the common form of treatment". So it seems that the reverse translating is not corrrect.

Comment: @Vlad I have never been impressed by computer translators, at least not free ones, which are the only ones I've ever tried.

Comment: But when I searched another similar by meaning words I got again treatment. For example "oral treatment". There is no "oral address".

Comment: @Vlad Oral treatment would be a medical process conducted on behalf of the mouth, and an oral address would be a speech delivered by speaking (as opposed to a speech in writing). I don't know Russian, but it seems like the translator isn't doing a good job understanding context.

Comment: Thanks. But I am discouraged now.

Comment: By words "contact someone" I mean to call or ask a stranger.

Comment: So, not in writing? Still, "form of address" applies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19779/discussion-between-daniel-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: No, not in writing. For example I would like to ask a passer-by or a policeman something. If I would know his exact name I would use the name. But how to ask if I do not know the name.